# Django custom manager keyword arguments

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have the following model.

```
class Site(models.Model):
   domain = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   subdomain = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

If a site has no subdomain I want it to default to `www`.  This is easy enough to do.  However, when `Site.objects.get(domain='example.com')` is called without a subdomain I want to set the subdomain to `www`.

I tried doing something like this:

```
class SitesManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'domain' in kwargs.keys() and 'subdomain' not in kwargs.keys():
            kwargs['subdomain'] = 'www'
        qs = super(SitesManager, self).get_queryset(args, kwargs)
        return qs

class Site(models.Model):
   domain = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   subdomain = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   objects = SitesManager()
```

but apparently `get_queryset` doesn't take additional arguments.  So what method am I supposed to override or how would I go about doing this?

**EDIT:**

The goal is to have only one site with the same domain and subdomain.  However, you might have multiple sites with the same domain, but different subdomains and vice versa.  So you can't make either domain or subdomain unique, but this was easy enough to handle in the save method so each domain subdomain combination is unique.

The problem I ran into was when trying to add sites by parsing links `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com` we're resulting in two different sites which isn't the desired outcome.  So my solution was to just default an empty subdomain to `www`.

The problem is that if you later parse `http://example.com` and try to get the site to see if it exists it will return that it doesn't.  @mad_wombat says you shouldn't return something the user didn't ask for, but if subdomain will never be empty and if it is empty it's actually supposed to be `www` then why wouldn't you return that?  I guess I could either do the sanitation check before every get call instead or do a custom method, that just seems like I'm adding something new rather than making the `get()` call work the way it is supposed to in this instance.

In more general terms, if a database field has a default value then it won't let you stick an empty value into that field, so doesn't it make more sense to not let the user request an empty value in that field than to tell them there are no results?

Comment: Incidentally, regardless of whether you should or shouldn't override the get method, can someone tell me how to do it.  There are plenty of things you "shouldn't" do in coding, it doesn't mean that it's not worth knowing how.  And since the original reason I posted this was because I couldn't find that answer anywhere it would probably be worth having the answer available to those that might want it.

Answer (score 0):

You can, of course, override get() and filter() and that will give you more or less the result you want. But you probably do not want to do that. QuerySet methods are a python API to RDBMS and your filter() and get() calls are python representation of SQL statements. And one thing people generally count on when talking to a database is that it will return what they ask for. What you are attempting to do here is to transparently return something the user didn't ask for. If you are the only user, nobody prevents you from checking if your subdomain is empty and getting 'www' by default

```
def get_site(domain, subdomain='www'):
    return Site.objects.get(domain=domain, subdomain=subdomain)
```

Or you can make this a manager method instead of a stand-alone function and call it like this

```
Site.objects.get_site(domain, subdomain)
```

But if other people will be using your code, they will not be expecting get() or filter() to do any magic substitutions.

Comment: @mad_wombat is spot on - you don't want any 'magic' happening in the get / filter calls. To add to his answer, you may need to ask yourself why you're doing this work. If the 'Site' object _requires_ a subdomain, you may want to override the 'save' method (or one of the 'clean' methods) to enforce this requirements.

Comment: @mad_wombat I edited my question.  I understand why you're saying in general you shouldn't return something the user didn't ask for.  However, I'm not sure why it is better to fail if somebody asks for an empty value that isn't possible than to simply return the default value that the empty value has been changed to.

Comment: For he actual answer you are looking for, you can, actually, override get() in manager. And looking at your edit, you don't have to insure uniqueness in save(), all you need is "unique_together" field in Meta https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Comment: It is probably still better to create a custom method than transparently override expected behavior

Comment: @MadWombat Thanks for the unique_together.  I went back and looked through my code.  I thought I used the call a lot more.  I actually only use it once.  Everything else was by id, so for now I'm following your advice.  Thanks.